# Volume-preserving Diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Anybody knows the conditions that a function $\gamma(x,t)$ with domain $(x,t)\in[0,1]\times[0,+\infty)$ and satisfying $\gamma_x(x,t)>0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ and $t\geq 0$ must satisfy in order for it to map, for each $t\in[0,+\infty)$, the unit interval to itself? Thanks!

Comment: For a fixed $t$ your mapping will map $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ so if it is continuous in $x$ which seems to be the case as you can compute partial derivative $\gamma_x(x,t)>0$ it will have a fixed point by Brouwer fixed point. That seems contradicting the fact that it is always increasing in $x$. Am I missing something or I just wrote a non-sense?

Comment: I don't think that $\gamma_x>0$ contradicts having a fixed point. For example $f(x)=x$ has $f'(x)>0$ and has infinitely many fixed points. I know the fact that $\gamma_x(x,t)>0$ implies that it has an inverse. I am just not sure as to whether that's enough to say that it maps $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I wish I could erase that non-sense I wrote. However the part which involves Brouwer fixed point theorem is valid. This is where I would start.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for - $\gamma(0,t)=0$ and $\gamma(1,t)=1$ seems to answer your question but also seems too obvious.

Comment: $\gamma(0,t)=0$ and $\gamma(1,t)=1$ would work, I think, but there could be other cases, such as $\gamma(1,t)=1+\gamma(0,t)$, which also appear to do the trick. So I wonder if there is more to the story. Something like criteria for a map to be a volume-preserving diffeomorphism.

Comment: So you just want it to map to *a* unit interval, not *the* unit interval then? Volume isn't very interesting in one dimension - global volume preservation is just your last equality, and local preservation restricts you to affine maps $\gamma(x,t) = f(t) + x$.